# Eliminar un solo valor duplicado de varios valores duplicados en python usando una sola variable

Tags: python, array, lista

Estaba programando cuando me tope con un problema que al yo tener esta lista `lista = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]` solamente queria eliminar los 1 y no los 2, pero para hacer eso habría que crearse una nueva lista y meter los valores 2 ahi pero es que no quiero crearme una nueva lista sino que en esa misma lista queden los valores de 2. Osea que me quede así `lista = [2, 2, 2, 2]`

Comment: Por que no quieres crear una nueva lista?

Comment: Osea, yo si podría crear una nueva lista pero quisiera saber como se podría hacer sin crear una

Comment: `lista = [x for x in lista if x==2]` De todas formas se crea una lista nueva. Si en verdad no quieres crear otra lista, deberías hacer `lista.remove(1)` n veces, donde n son las veces que se repite el `1`

Comment: Gracias bro sos un capo, si me sirvió

Comment: problema con `.remove()` es que suelta una excepcion de tipo ValueError si no existe el valor a eliminar. @KevinTorrecilla tenlo en cuenta y capturala con un try/except

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa es recorrer la lista desde el final hacia el principio eliminando cada elemento indeseado.

```
lista = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(lista) - 1, -1, -1):
    if lista[i] == 1:
        del lista[i]

print(lista)
```

produce:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Esta forma, a diferencia del uso de remove, recorre la lista una vez, por lo que es más rápido. No se como no lo pensé. +1. Solo una cosa. Por que recorres la lista desde el final hasta el principio y no al reves?

Comment: Si vas de izquierda a derecha, no debes incrementar `i` cuando eliminas un elemento. En el sentido contrario, no necesitas discriminar: siempre decrementas.

Comment: una pregunta también se puede utilizar remove?

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción, un tanto esotérica:

```
lista[:] = filter(lambda x: x!=1, lista)
```

Esto aplica un filtro (invocando la función `lambda` sobre cada elemento) y crea una nueva lista sólo con los elementos que pasen el filtro (ser distintos de 1). En realidad lo mismo se podría hacer con una *comprensión de listas*, pero la gracia de esta solución no es el usar el filtro, sino la asignación del resultado.

El resultado se está asignando de nuevo a `lista[:]`, por lo que la nueva lista **sustituye el contenido** de `lista`, pero sin alterar la referencia, por lo en realidad la modifica "in situ".

Una demo de que esto es así:

```
def quitar_unos(lista):
  lista[:] = filter(lambda x: x!=1, lista)

l = [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
quitar_unos(l)
print(l)
```

Sale

```
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```